# Calculate Rectangle area of an image

Tags: java, imagej

I am new in image processing and need simple things to do my work , all I have to do is calculate Width and Hight of rectangle of an image in java programming with ImageJ , is it possible

And thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are already defined methods for different classes. Just make sure you are using correct class object and use methods like getHeight and getWidth. You can use this link to learn about the api's of ImageJ https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html